# Can I change the icons used in the quick settings?

Tags: quick-settings

I have a new phone, and the icons in the quick settings are ugly in my opinion.

Can I change the icons used here easily, and if so how? (I see similar icons in the normal settings, i am happy if those change as well).

Andoriod 7.0

Comment: You can find a substratum theme with your choice of icons and use it. Search them on Play Store. Requires a rooted device though.

Comment: Not got a rooted device, and it sounds like more effort than its worth for changing those icons.